# xunitmerge does creates duplicate tests when merged the py.test results of two different set of tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, jenkins, pytest, xunit

xunitmerge create duplicate tests when merged the py.test results of two different set of tests.

I have two test folders and ran them separately using py.test, which created results-1.xml &results-2.xml. after that i am merging as below.

xunitmerge results-1.xml results-2.xml results.xml

which created results.xml, when i publish the results using jenkins (publish xunit results) i see the tests recorded shown them as duplicate though the tests of results-1.xml and results-2.xml are unique.

How to avoid duplicate test results during merge?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you didn't include the original results-1.xml and results-2.xml file in the path that Jenkins scan for results.
If you're not sure about it, try to delete the origin files after the merge (and before running the xunit-report action)